# np.random.choice exclude certain numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm supposed to create code that will simulate a d20 sided dice rolling 25 times using `np.random.choice`.

I tried this:

```
np.random.choice(20,25)
```

but this still includes 0's which wouldn't appear on a dice.

How do I account for the 0's?

Answer (score 1):

Use [np.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)  # for reproducibility

result = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 21), 50)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[ 7 20 15 11  8  7 19 11 11  4  8  3  2 12  6  2  1 12 12 17 10 16 15 15
 19 12 20  3  5 19  7  9  7 18  4 14 18  9  2 20 15  7 12  8 15  3 14 17
  4 18]
```

The above code draws numbers from 0 to 20 both inclusive. To understand why, you could check the documentation of [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice), in particular on the first argument:

> a : 1-D array-like or int
>
> If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements. If an
> int, the random sample is generated as if a was np.arange(n)

Answer (score 0):

np.random.choice() takes as its first argument an array of possible choices (if int is given it works like np.arrange), so you can use list(range(1, 21)) to get the output you want

Answer (score 0):

+1

```
np.random.choice(20,25) + 1
```